# Spring : java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm trying a Hello World application with Spring 4.0.2 and Maven.

I am deploying on Tomcat v9.

I get the following error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:84)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(RequestContextUtils.java:89)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.initContext(RequestContext.java:237)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.JspAwareRequestContext.initContext(JspAwareRequestContext.java:74)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.JspAwareRequestContext.<init>(JspAwareRequestContext.java:48)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:77)
at org.apache.jsp.vues.bonjour_jsp._jspx_meth_spring_005fmessage_005f0(bonjour_jsp.java:169)
at org.apache.jsp.vues.bonjour_jsp._jspService(bonjour_jsp.java:125)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:444)
...
```

Following is my web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">


    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

</web-app>
```

Following is my dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="ISO-8859-1" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

Following is my file message_fr.properties in the resources folder:

```
titre.bonjour=Bonjour avec Spring
libelle.bonjour.lemonde=Bonjour le monde avec Spring.
```

and my jsp file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><spring:message code="titre.bonjour"/></title>
</head>
<body>
    <spring:message code="libelle.bonjour.lemonde"/>
</body>
</html>
```

All inputs appreciated.

Comment: You don't have a `DispatcherServlet` so the use of the `spring` tags in your JSP won't work. The JSP needs to be served through the `DispatcherServlet`.

Comment: your web.xml seems really short. As you are french:  Je te demande de revoir la configuration de ton projet. Ton web.xml est insuffisant il manque le contexte de la servlet.